# scichart how to delete left and right MajorGridLines

Tags: wpf, scichart

I custom TickProvider,and the MajorGridLines is show correct.
but it's weird on the left and right.

There is double line,how to delete left and right MajorGridLines and show label on the left and right?

[image: here is the current effect]

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say. Have you pointed WPF Snoop at your applicaiton to determine the source of the line?

Things it could be:

1. It could be a gridline from your own TickProvider output
2. It could be the right border of the SciChartSurface.RenderSurface or SciChartSurface.Gridlinespanel
3. It could be the left border of the NumericAxis on the right

Have a look at the documentation on [Templating and Styling Chart Parts](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/Templating%20and%20Styling%20Chart%20Parts.html) to see what parts of the chart you can colour and how.